# Doxygen How to avoid" Multiple markers at this line"

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I Have two files with the same name but in two different directories.

```
 graphic_test ---semLib.c
               |
               |
               -- vxWorksApi---semLib.c
```

I want to build a Html with Doxygen. this is the header of the file semLib.c

```
 /**
 * @file    semLib.c
*/
```

And I got this message

```
 Multiple markers at this line
        - the name `semLib.c' supplied as the second argument in the \file statement matches the following input files: /home/linuxdev/
         Linux_Development_Workspace/graphic_tests/graphic_test/semLib.c /home/linuxdev/Linux_Development_Workspace/graphic_tests/vxWorksApi/semLib.c
        - Line breakpoint: semLib.c [line: 2]
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Do the two "semLib.c" have the same content ?

Comment: @PascalLécuyot NO, the second one even don't have a doxygen comment

Comment: Can you try just having `* \file` at the top of each file not `* @file semLib.c`, i.e. get rid of the filename, and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

From the [doxygen documentation for the `\file` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile) (emphasis mine):

> `\file`
>
> Indicates that a comment block contains documentation for a source or header file with name `<name>`. **The file name may include (part of) the path if the file-name alone is not unique.**

So try using `\file semLib.c` and `\file vxWorksApi/semLib.c` in the appropriate files.

Comment: It what way does this not work - can you be more specific? Perhaps update your question to include any errors generated when you tried this suggestion.

Comment: Sry for my inaccuracy. It is the same behavior like befor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and making the above change still didn't work:
"So try using \file semLib.c and \file vxWorksApi/semLib.c in the appropriate files."

My situation is different as the files are in separate but parallel folders and this worked for me:
\file xdir/semLib.c and \file ydir/semLib.c in the appropriate files.

For your purposes try adding the full path or a partial path for both:
\file adir/xdir/semLib.c and \file adir/ydir/semLib.c in the appropriate files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but doesn't help to have only one file changed. You need to have both paths changed

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What did you exactly change, i.e. how does it look like now?